# Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?

Tags: c, fgets, buffer-overflow, gets

When I try to compile C code that uses the `gets()` function with GCC, I get this warning:

> (.text+0x34): warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.

I remember this has something to do with stack protection and security, but I'm not sure exactly why.

How can I remove this warning and why is there such a warning about using `gets()`?

If `gets()` is so dangerous then why can't we remove it?

Comment: [`gets()` Buffer_overflow_attack](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_overflow_attack)

Comment: [more explanation_Bufferoverflow_C `gets()`](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow4.html)

Comment: And note that `scanf("%s", b)` has all the same problems as `gets`.

Comment: As a measure of how seriously even WG14 (the ISO working group responsible for the C standard) take this, it is, so far, the ONLY feature formally removed from the C standard.  WG14 have a policy of *never break existing code* (even if already fundamentally broken) - a policy they broke to get rid of `gets()`!

Answer (score 222, accepted):

In order to use `gets` safely, you have to know exactly how many characters you will be reading, so that you can make your buffer large enough. You will only know that if you know exactly what data you will be reading.

Instead of using `gets`, you want to use [`fgets`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which has the signature

```
char* fgets(char *string, int length, FILE * stream);
```

(`fgets`, if it reads an entire line, will leave the `'\n'` in the string; you'll have to deal with that.)

`gets` remained an official part of the language up to the 1999 ISO C standard, but it was officially removed in the [2011 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Most C implementations still support it, but at least gcc issues a warning for any code that uses it.

Comment: It's actually not gcc which warns, it's the glibc which contains a pragma or attribute on `gets()` that causes the compiler to emit a warning when used.

Comment: @fuz actually, it's not even only the compiler that warns: the warning quoted in the OP was printed by the linker!

Answer (score 242):

## Why is `gets()` dangerous

The first internet worm (the [Morris Internet Worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morris_worm)) escaped about 30 years ago (1988-11-02), and it used `gets()` and a buffer overflow as one of its methods of propagating from system to system. The basic problem is that the function doesn't know how big the buffer is, so it continues reading until it finds a newline or encounters EOF, and may overflow the bounds of the buffer it was given.

You should forget you ever heard that `gets()` existed.

The C11 standard ISO/IEC 9899:2011 eliminated `gets()` as a standard function, which is A Good Thing™ (it was formally marked as 'obsolescent' and 'deprecated' in ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007 — Technical Corrigendum 3 for C99, and then removed in C11). Sadly, it will remain in libraries for many years (meaning 'decades') for reasons of backwards compatibility. If it were up to me, the implementation of `gets()` would become:

```
char *gets(char *buffer)
{
    assert(buffer != 0);
    abort();
    return 0;
}
```

Given that your code will crash anyway, sooner or later, it is better to head the trouble off sooner rather than later. I'd be prepared to add an error message:

```
fputs("obsolete and dangerous function gets() called\n", stderr);
```

Modern versions of the Linux compilation system generates warnings if you link `gets()` — and also for some other functions that also have security problems (`mktemp()`, …).

## Alternatives to `gets()`

### fgets()

As everyone else said, the canonical alternative to `gets()` is [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) specifying `stdin` as the file stream.

```
char buffer[BUFSIZ];

while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) != 0)
{
    ...process line of data...
}
```

What no-one else yet mentioned is that `gets()` does not include the newline but `fgets()` does. So, you might need to use a wrapper around `fgets()` that deletes the newline:

```
char *fgets_wrapper(char *buffer, size_t buflen, FILE *fp)
{
    if (fgets(buffer, buflen, fp) != 0)
    {
        size_t len = strlen(buffer);
        if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
            buffer[len-1] = '\0';
        return buffer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or, better:

```
char *fgets_wrapper(char *buffer, size_t buflen, FILE *fp)
{
    if (fgets(buffer, buflen, fp) != 0)
    {
        buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = '\0';
        return buffer;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Also, as caf points out [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used#comment4680288_4309845) and paxdiablo shows in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used/4309871#4309871), with `fgets()` you might have data left over on a line. My wrapper code leaves that data to be read next time; you can readily modify it to gobble the rest of the line of data if you prefer:

```
        if (len > 0 && buffer[len-1] == '\n')
            buffer[len-1] = '\0';
        else
        {
             int ch;
             while ((ch = getc(fp)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
                 ;
        }
```

The residual problem is how to report the three different result states — EOF or error, line read and not truncated, and partial line read but data was truncated.

This problem doesn't arise with `gets()` because it doesn't know where your buffer ends and merrily tramples beyond the end, wreaking havoc on your beautifully tended memory layout, often messing up the return stack (a [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)) if the buffer is allocated on the stack, or trampling over the control information if the buffer is dynamically allocated, or copying data over other precious global (or module) variables if the buffer is statically allocated. None of these is a good idea — they epitomize the phrase 'undefined behaviour`.

---

There is also the [TR 24731-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/372980/do-you-use-the-tr-24731-safe-functions-in-your-c-code) (Technical Report from the C Standard Committee) which provides safer alternatives to a variety of functions, including `gets()`:

> ### §6.5.4.1 The `gets_s` function

> ###Synopsis

> ```
> #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);
> ```

> #### Runtime-constraints
>
> `s` shall not be a null pointer. `n` shall neither be equal to zero nor be greater than RSIZE_MAX. A new-line character, end-of-file, or read error shall occur within reading `n-1` characters from `stdin`.<sup>25)</sup>

> 3 If there is a runtime-constraint violation, `s[0]` is set to the null character, and characters are read and discarded from `stdin` until a new-line character is read, or end-of-file or a read error occurs.

> #### Description

> 4 The `gets_s` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by `stdin`, into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is discarded) or after end-of-file. The discarded new-line character does not count towards number of characters read. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

> 5 If end-of-file is encountered and no characters have been read into the array, or if a read error occurs during the operation, then `s[0]` is set to the null character, and the other elements of `s` take unspecified values.

> #### Recommended practice

> 6 The `fgets` function allows properly-written programs to safely process input lines too long to store in the result array. In general this requires that callers of `fgets` pay attention to the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array. Consider using `fgets` (along with any needed processing based on new-line characters) instead of `gets_s`.

> <sup>25)</sup> The `gets_s` function, unlike `gets`, makes it a runtime-constraint violation for a line of input to overflow the buffer to store it. Unlike `fgets`, `gets_s` maintains a one-to-one relationship between input lines and successful calls to `gets_s`. Programs that use `gets` expect such a relationship.

The Microsoft Visual Studio compilers implement an approximation to the TR 24731-1 standard, but there are differences between the signatures implemented by Microsoft and those in the TR.

The C11 standard, ISO/IEC 9899-2011, includes TR24731 in Annex K as an optional part of the library. Unfortunately, it is seldom implemented on Unix-like systems.

---

### `getline()` — POSIX

POSIX 2008 also provides a safe alternative to `gets()` called [`getline()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html). It allocates space for the line dynamically, so you end up needing to free it. It removes the limitation on line length, therefore. It also returns the length of the data that was read, or `-1` (and not `EOF`!), which means that null bytes in the input can be handled reliably. There is also a 'choose your own single-character delimiter' variation called `getdelim()`; this can be useful if you are dealing with the output from `find -print0` where the ends of the file names are marked with an ASCII NUL `'\0'` character, for example.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that `fgets()` and your `fgets_wrapper()` version will leave the trailing portion of an over-long line in the input buffer, to be read by the next input function.  In many cases, you will want to read-and-discard these characters.

Comment: I wonder why they didn't add an fgets() alternative that allows one to use its functionality without having to make a silly strlen call.  For example, an fgets variant which returned the number of bytes read into the string would make it easy for code to see if the last byte read was a newline.  If the behavior of passing a null pointer for the buffer was defined as "read and discard up to n-1 bytes until the next newline", that would allow code to easily discard the tail of over-length lines.

Comment: @supercat: Yes, I agree -- it is a pity. The nearest approach to that is probably POSIX [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)
and its relative `getdelim()`, which do return the length of the 'line' read by the commands, allocating space as required to be able to store the whole line. Even that can cause problems if you end up with a single-line JSON file that is multiple gigabytes in size; can you afford all that memory? (And while we're at it, can we have `strcpy()` and `strcat()` variants that return a pointer to the null byte at the end? Etc.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: What makes the fgets() situation particularly annoying is that on many systems there's no way to write a user function which behaves like fgets() but is anywhere near as fast.  The same may be true of a few strcpy() implementations, but most will be comparable in speed to either strlen+memmove or to a simple character-by-character copy loop.

Comment: @supercat: the other problem with `fgets()` is that if the file contains a null byte, you can't tell how much data there is after the null byte up to the end of line (or EOF).  `strlen()` can only report up to the null byte in the data; after that, it is guesswork and therefore almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Indeed that's a problem with `fgets()`.  My point was that the lack of a decent string-concatenation function in the standard library doesn't prevent a programmer from writing one, but on many systems there's no portable way to write an `fgets()` replacement that will yield decent performance.

Comment: Seems to me you abandoned any regret that Unix-like systems abstain from Annex K [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/373911/3204551)...

Comment: @Deduplicator: Mostly, yes. Until I found that Microsoft's implementation didn't match the Annex K interface (even approximately; the number of arguments varies between the two for some functions), I had hopes that using Annex K (TR 24731-1) functions would allow for source code portability between Unix and Windows without needing conditional compilation and without requiring compiler-specific pragmata to suppress warnings, etc. Because they're different, they don't help after all. Sad, but so — [IMNSHO](http://www.acronymfinder.com/In-My-Not-So-Humble-Opinion-%28IMNSHO%29.html) of course.

Comment: "forget you ever heard that `gets()` existed."  When I do this I run into it again and come back here.  Are you hacking stackoverflow to get upvotes?

Comment: Considering worms, evil users and user input: the only way to get a null character before a `'\n'` is 1) if the user enters a null character as part of input.  2) Buffer is full 3) or maybe buffer size if pathologically small like 1, 0, or negative. Consider input <null character> <Enter>.  This answer will enter the `\n` consuming `while` loop attempting to eat the _next_ `\n`.  `fgets()` is much better than `gets()`, but retains corner weaknesses.

Comment: `getline()` is OK, but does not limit user input.  This allows the evil user to consume/control memory usage.  A robust user input function would limit the user input to some sane upper bound like `fgets()` and report the length read, like `getline()`.  Should the buffer be pre-allocated or adjusted on the fly is of secondary concern.  All-in-all I like your answer though.

Comment: @chux: Typically, when you get `'\0'` before `'\n'`, you're reading some sort of binary file (eg an executable) instead of the text file you expected — line-based input doesn't make sense on binary files, usually. But `fgets()` doesn't allow you to detect reliably how much data was read if the input contains any null bytes. If you're worried about memory over-consumption, then you have to write your own variant on POSIX `getline()` — it isn't very hard to write `getline()` (I've done it), and after you've designed an appropriate interface specifying the upper bound, neither is the alternative.

Comment: As you introduced the Morris Internet Worm, code considerations here are beyond typical.  Also note that many text based files use UTF-16 encoding contain many null characters and using `fgets()` to inadvertently read one of those is a real possibility.  Yes - writing ones own wrapper is likely the only way to defend against evil or errant user input.

Comment: [Chuck Falconer's public domain `ggets` function](http://www.taenarum.com/software/ggets/) is a good alternative for systems where `getline` is unavailable.

Comment: @jamesdlin `ggets()` has  weaknesses: [poor](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm) realloc growth, wrong return value on input error, uses non-standard error code, other minor issues.

Comment: In hindsight, I wish that we hadn't deprecated `gets`, but instead, retroactively redefined it to take a `bufsize` parameter.  Yes, this would have caused some confusion, but it wouldn't be any worse than the confusion that has ensued since deprecating and deleting it.

Answer (score 27):

Because `gets` doesn't do any kind of check while getting bytes from *stdin* and putting them somewhere. A simple example:

```
char array1[] = "12345";
char array2[] = "67890";

gets(array1);
```

Now, first of all you are allowed to input how many characters you want, `gets` won't care about it. Secondly the bytes over the size of the array in which you put them (in this case `array1`) will overwrite whatever they find in memory because `gets` will write them. In the previous example this means that if you input `"abcdefghijklmnopqrts"` maybe, unpredictably, it will overwrite also `array2` or whatever.

The function is unsafe because it assumes consistent input. **NEVER USE IT!**

Comment: What makes `gets` outright unusable is that it doesn't have an array length/count parameter that it takes; had it been there, it'd just be another ordinary C standard function.

Comment: @legends2k: I'm curious what the intended usage for `gets` was, and why no standard fgets variant was made as convenient for use cases where the newline is not desired as part of the input?

Comment: @supercat `gets` was, as the name suggests, designed to get a string from `stdin`, however the rationale for not having a _size_ parameter may have been from _the spirit of C_: Trust the programmer. This function was removed in _C11_ and the replacement given [`gets_s`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) takes in the size of the input buffer. I've no clue about the `fgets` part though.

Comment: @legends2k: The only context I can see in which `gets` might be excusable would be if one was using a hardware-line-buffered I/O system which was physically incapable of submitting a line over a certain length, and the intended lifetime of the program was shorter than the lifetime of the hardware.  In that case, if hardware is incapable of submitting lines over 127 bytes long it might be justifiable to `gets` into a 128-byte buffer, though I would think the advantages of being able to specify a shorter buffer when expecting smaller input would more than justify the cost.

Comment: @legends2k: Actually, what might have been ideal would have been to have a "string pointer" identify a byte that would select among a few different string/buffer/buffer-info formats, with one value of prefix byte indicating a struct that contained the prefix byte [plus padding], plus the buffer size, used size, and address of the actual text.  Such a pattern would make it possible for code to pass an arbitrary substring (not just the tail) of another string without having to copy anything, and would allow methods like `gets` and `strcat` to safely accept as much as will fit.

Comment: @legends2k: A buffer holding strings up to 63 bytes would only need one byte of overhead (use 63 prefix-byte values to indicate a "full" buffer, and 63 to indicate a buffer whose last byte will indicate the length of the string therein).  Longer strings would have more overhead.  Code which could receive an arbitrary string would call a standard-library function to generate a space+length+data structure; code that needed to resize a string could call a standard-library function to do that [if a prefix-byte value were used for "indirect reference to heap-allocated string, ...

Comment: ...such a resize method could even perform `realloc` on heap-allocated strings, making it possible for a `gets` which accepted just a string parameter to accept either a direct reference to a small array on a local stack, or a reference to an "auto-sizing heap string" descriptor (allowing heap storage to be allocated as needed).

Comment: Communication with a forked-off child process that runs the same executable as the parent might be a perfectly safe use of `gets` because then you control both the reader and the writer.

Comment: @supercat *"and the intended lifetime of the program was shorter than the lifetime of the hardware"* - Nope, that's not excusable. The intended lifetime of a program is often shorter than it's real lifetime.

Answer (score 19):

You should not use `gets` since it has no way to stop a buffer overflow. If the user types in more data than can fit in your buffer, you will most likely end up with corruption or worse.

In fact, ISO have actually taken the step of *removing* `gets` from the C standard (as of C11, though it was deprecated in C99) which, given how highly they rate backward compatibility, should be an indication of how bad that function was.

The correct thing to do is to use the `fgets` function with the `stdin` file handle since you can limit the characters read from the user.

But this also has its problems such as:

- extra characters entered by the user will be picked up the next time around.
- there's no quick notification that the user entered too much data.

To that end, almost every C coder at some point in their career will write a more useful wrapper around `fgets` as well. Here's mine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OK       0
#define NO_INPUT 1
#define TOO_LONG 2
static int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) {
    int ch, extra;

    // Get line with buffer overrun protection.
    if (prmpt != NULL) {
        printf ("%s", prmpt);
        fflush (stdout);
    }
    if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)
        return NO_INPUT;

    // If it was too long, there'll be no newline. In that case, we flush
    // to end of line so that excess doesn't affect the next call.
    if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {
        extra = 0;
        while (((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && (ch != EOF))
            extra = 1;
        return (extra == 1) ? TOO_LONG : OK;
    }

    // Otherwise remove newline and give string back to caller.
    buff[strlen(buff)-1] = '\0';
    return OK;
}
```

with some test code:

```
// Test program for getLine().

int main (void) {
    int rc;
    char buff[10];

    rc = getLine ("Enter string> ", buff, sizeof(buff));
    if (rc == NO_INPUT) {
        printf ("No input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (rc == TOO_LONG) {
        printf ("Input too long\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf ("OK [%s]\n", buff);

    return 0;
}
```

It provides the same protections as `fgets` in that it prevents buffer overflows but it also notifies the caller as to what happened and clears out the excess characters so that they do not affect your next input operation.

Feel free to use it as you wish, I hereby release it under the "do what you damn well want to" licence :-)

Comment: Actually, the original C99 standard did not explicitly deprecate `gets()` either in section 7.19.7.7 where it is defined or in section 7.26.9 Future library directions and the sub-section for `<stdio.h>`.  There isn't even a footnote on it being dangerous.  (Having said that, I see "It's deprecated in ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E))" in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19205993) by [Yu Hao](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1009479).)  But C11 did remove it from the standard — and not before time!

Comment: `int getLine (char *prmpt, char *buff, size_t sz) { ... if (fgets (buff, sz, stdin) == NULL)` hides the `size_t` to `int` conversion of `sz`.  `sz > INT_MAX || sz < 2` would catch strange values of `sz`.

Comment: `if (buff[strlen(buff)-1] != '\n') {` is a hacker exploit as the evil user's first character entered could be an embedded null character rendering `buff[strlen(buff)-1]` UB.  `while (((ch = getchar())...` has troubles should a user enter a null character.

Answer (score 16):

[fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/).

To read from the stdin:

```
char string[512];

fgets(string, sizeof(string), stdin); /* no buffer overflows here, you're safe! */
```

Answer (score 12):

You can't remove API functions without breaking the API. If you would, many applications would no longer compile or run at all.

This is the reason that [one reference](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/gets.html) gives:

> Reading a line that overflows the
>   array pointed to by s results in
>   undefined behavior. The use of fgets()
>   is recommended.

Answer (score 6):

I read recently, in a [USENET post to `comp.lang.c`](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/7e92710bc5ff2ba8), that `gets()` is getting removed from the Standard. **WOOHOO**

> You'll be happy to know that the
>   committee just voted (unanimously, as
>   it turns out) to remove gets() from
>   the draft as well.

Comment: It is excellent that it is being removed from the standard.  However, most implementations will provide it as a 'now non-standard extension' for at least the next 20 years, because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: Yes, right, but when you compile with `gcc -std=c2012 -pedantic ...` gets() will not get through. (I just made up the `-std` parameter)

Answer (score 5):

In C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x), `gets()` has been removed. (It's deprecated in ISO/IEC 9899:1999/Cor.3:2007(E))

In addition to `fgets()`, C11 introduces a new safe alternative `gets_s()`:

> #### C11 K.3.5.4.1 The `gets_s` function
>
> ```
> #define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1
> #include <stdio.h>
> char *gets_s(char *s, rsize_t n);
> ```

However, in the *Recommended practice* section, `fgets()` is still preferred.

> The `fgets` function allows properly-written programs to safely process input lines too
>   long to store in the result array. In general this requires that callers of `fgets` pay
>   attention to the presence or absence of a new-line character in the result array. Consider
>   using `fgets` (along with any needed processing based on new-line characters) instead of
>   `gets_s`.

Comment: If they remove fgets() there are always options like scanf("%s", arr) or getline(&arr, 100500, stdin). This is a nuisance of course because when you want to write some shitty code you generally also want to do it as quickly as possible and with minimal brainpower usage. I hope the implementations will stop at just the warnings.

Comment: @mrKirushko: Your `scanf("%s", arr)` option is just as broken as `gets()`.

Answer (score 5):

`gets()` is dangerous because it is possible for the user to crash the program by typing too much into the prompt. It can't detect the end of available memory, so if you allocate an amount of memory too small for the purpose, it can cause a seg fault and crash. Sometimes it seems very unlikely that a user will type 1000 letters into a prompt meant for a person's name, but as programmers, we need to make our programs bulletproof. (it may also be a security risk if a user can crash a system program by sending too much data).

`fgets()` allows you to specify how many characters are taken out of the standard input buffer, so they don't overrun the variable.

Comment: Note that the real danger is not in being able to *crash* your program, but in being able to make it *run arbitrary code*. (In general, exploiting *undefined behavior*.)

Answer (score 3):

The C gets function is dangerous and has been a very costly mistake. Tony Hoare singles it out for specific mention in his talk "Null References: The Billion Dollar Mistake":

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare

The whole hour is worth watching but for his comments view from 30 minutes on with the specific gets criticism around 39 minutes.

Hopefully this whets your appetite for the whole talk, which draws attention to how we need more formal correctness proofs in languages and how language designers should be blamed for the mistakes in their languages, not the programmer. This seems to have been the whole dubious reason for designers of bad languages to push the blame to programmers in the guise of 'programmer freedom'.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to extend an earnest invitation to any C library maintainers out there who are still including `gets` in their libraries "just in case anyone is still depending on it": Please replace your implementation with the equivalent of

```
char *gets(char *str)
{
    strcpy(str, "Never use gets!");
    return str;
}
```

This will help make sure nobody is still depending on it.  Thank you.

Comment: Even if they remove fgets() there are always options like scanf("%s", arr) or getline(&arr, 100500, stdin) available. This is still a nuisance of course because when you want to write some shitty code you generally also want to do it as quickly as possible and with minimal brainpower usage. I hope the implementations will stop at just the warnings.

Comment: @mrKirushko Why would they remove `fgets()`? that is safe unlike `gets()`

Answer (score 1):

Additional info:

From `man 3 gets` on Linux Ubuntu you'll see (emphasis added):

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>        Never use this function.
> ```

And, from the cppreference.com wiki here (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) you'll see: `Notes  Never use gets().`:

> ### Notes
>
> The `gets()` function does not perform bounds checking, therefore this function is extremely vulnerable to buffer-overflow attacks. It cannot be used safely (unless the program runs in an environment which restricts what can appear on `stdin`). For this reason, the function has been deprecated in the third corrigendum to the C99 standard and removed altogether in the C11 standard. `fgets()` and `gets_s()` are the recommended replacements.
>
> **Never use `gets()`.**

As you can see, the function has been deprecated and removed entirely in C11 or later.

Use [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) or [`gets_s()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets) instead.

Here is my demo usage of `fgets()`, with full error checking:

From [**read_stdin_fgets_basic_input_from_user.c**](https://github.com/ElectricRCAircraftGuy/eRCaGuy_hello_world/blob/master/c/read_stdin_fgets_basic_input_from_user.c):

```c
#include <errno.h>   // `errno`
#include <stdio.h>   // `printf()`, `fgets()`
#include <stdlib.h>  // `exit()`
#include <string.h>  // `strerror()`

// int main(int argc, char *argv[])  // alternative prototype
int main()
{
    char buf[10];

    // NEVER USE `gets()`! USE `fgets()` BELOW INSTEAD!

    // USE THIS!: `fgets()`: "file get string", which reads until either EOF is
    // reached, OR a newline (`\n`) is found, keeping the newline char in
    // `buf`.
    // For `feof()` and `ferror()`, see:
    // 1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof
    // 1. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ferror
    printf("Enter up to %zu chars: ", sizeof(buf) - 1); // - 1 to save room
                                                        // for null terminator
    char* retval = fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
    if (feof(stdin))
    {
        // Check for `EOF`, which means "End of File was reached".
        // - This doesn't really make sense on `stdin` I think, but it is a good
        //   check to have when reading from a regular file with `fgets
        //   ()`. Keep it here regardless, just in case.
        printf("EOF (End of File) reached.\n");
    }
    if (ferror(stdin))
    {
        printf("Error indicator set. IO error when reading from file "
               "`stdin`.\n");
    }
    if (retval == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in %s(): fgets() failed; errno = %i: %s\n",
            __func__, errno, strerror(errno));

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    size_t num_chars_written = strlen(buf) + 1; // + 1 for null terminator
    if (num_chars_written >= sizeof(buf))
    {
        printf("Warning: user input may have been truncated! All %zu chars "
               "were written into buffer.\n", num_chars_written);
    }
    printf("You entered \"%s\".\n", buf);


    return 0;
}
```

Sample runs and output:

```
eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_stdin_fgets_basic_input_from_user.c -o bin/a && bin/a
Enter up to 9 chars: hello world!
Warning: user input may have been truncated! All 10 chars were written into buffer.
You entered "hello wor".

eRCaGuy_hello_world/c$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -std=c17 read_stdin_fgets_basic_input_from_user.c -o bin/a && bin/a
Enter up to 9 chars: hey
You entered "hey
".
```

Answer (score 0):

In a few words `gets()` (can) be dangerous because the user might input something bigger than what the variable has enough space to store. First answer says about `fgets()` and why it is safer.

Comment: This answer is just unnecessarily repeating what others have already said.

Comment: @jpa true. I just wanted to say it in as fewer words as possible